# New Relic response time more than all segments combined

Tags: java, spring-boot, grpc, newrelic

Can someone explain what is this extra time other than all the segments combined.
I am running a **java-grpc** server using **Springboot** with **grpc** plugin.

[image: NewRelic Segments]

Comment: Did you upgrade NewRelic Agent lately ? (5.2.0 or more)

Comment: using "com.newrelic.agent.java:newrelic-api:6.4.2"